# Notification Center fire UIPasteboardChanged from Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uipasteboard, notificationcenter

I have registered a notification as follows:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
     selector: #selector(functionName),
     name: NSNotification.Name.UIPasteboardChanged,
     object: nil);
```

which calls a function:

```
func functionName(){
    print("changed");
}
```

The notification fires when the user copies and pastes within the app, however, it does not fire when a user copies from another app like Safari.

Here is the usage case I am trying to fire the notification with:
a user has both my app and Safari up side-by-side on an iPad. The user copies something from Safari, and my app automatically detects that the user has copied something and processes the pasteboard.

3 Related Questions:

1. I have read that `CFNotificationCenter` is the more appropriate Notification Center to handle these requests, is this correct in this usage case?
2. Does this violate "sandboxing" which is why the notification only fires on changes made locally to the app?
3. Is there a work-around to have the function fire on `UIPasteboardChanged` as I would like it to?

Answer (score 0):

If your APP into the background, and there is no background activity, your APP will not be able to receive the notice. You can keep the user copies and pastes when get the notification. Then your App enter foreground ,you can compare the new copies and pastes.

Comment: If both apps are in the foreground? The question specifies side-by-side apps. Any ideas?